# Is it possible to have one ip on main domain and a different ip on a trailing slash domain

Tags: domain-name-system

Lets say I have a site, `example.com` which points to `111.11.111.11`

Would it be possible for me to have `example.com/landing-page` on `222.22.222.22`?

If so, what kind of DNS record would I have to add?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is a "trailing slash domain"? That makes no sense to me: slashes are illegal in domain names, so you can't have a trailing slash or any slash at all in a domain name.

Answer (score 3):

No, because in your example `/landing-page` is an url-path, which is in this case, simply put, a concept of HTTP protocol.

Your option for a custom DNS is to use a subdomain, e.g.:
`landing-page.example.com/`

You can easily test it in your own machine, simply changing the configuration in `hosts` file.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this with a webserver like nginx that forwards to an upstream webserver any request for `/landing-page` or any other reverse proxy server, like some types of load balancer that act at the http-level of the network stack.

DNS is mainly used to return just an ip-address, only once that is known and connected with, can be sent an HTTP request like:

`GET /landing-page`

So no, DNS doesn't help here.